# How to SUM() OVER() by pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

MY data like
|  ID | Values |
|:---:|:------:|
|  1  |  200   |
|  2  |  300   |
|  3  |  650   |
|  4  |  120   |
|  5  |  830   |

I want : T-SQL : `SUM(Values) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Sum`

| ID | Values | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 200 |
| 2 | 300 | 500 |
| 3 | 650 | 1150 |
| 4 | 120 | 1270 |
| 5 | 830 | 2100 |

How should I do by pentaho??

Answer (score 0):

You use the "Group by" step with the *Cumulative sum* option, and without filling the *Group field* section so it performs the sum for all the rows:
[image]

You'll have to feed the data ordered by ID with a *Sort* step, in my screenshot I haven't put the Sort step because I have fill up the Data grid with the data ordered, but in your case you might need to make sure the data is ordered first.